# If $f(x)=f(xe^t)$, Then prove that $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\forall x \in R$ and $ t \geq 0$, $f(x)=f(xe^t)$. Then prove that $f$ is a constant function.

This is what I did:
For a typical $t =t_0$ we have:
$$f(x)=f(xe^{t_0}) \to (1)$$
Now plugging $x=1$ above we get:
$$f(1)=f(e^{t_0}) \to (2)$$
Also plugging in $x=e^{-t_0}$ in $(1)$ we get:
$$f(e^{-t_0})=f(1)\to (3)$$
So from $(2),(3)$ we have:
$$f(e^{-t_0})=f(e^{t_0}) \to (4)$$
Similarly we get:
$$f(-e^{-t_0})=f(-e^{t_0})\to (5)$$
from $(4),(5)$ we get:
$$f(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \forall x \in R-\{0\}$$
Any way to proceed from here?

Comment: Is t a constant or is it a parameter?

Comment: It is a parameter i guess, but nothing is specified as such

Comment: You need to use continuity at $x=0$ to show positive and negative numbers both give the same value

Comment: if $t=0 \forall x $ then $f(x)=f(x)$ or we can say nothing about f

Comment: As a hint, try letting $t=\ln(y/x)$.